# Does DotNetNuke have anything similar to Drupal's CCK?

Tags: drupal, dotnetnuke, cck

I'm building a content website whose basic elements are not just plain text but rather structures containing multiple fields. I want it to be based on open source CMS so that I can extend/tweak it as I wish.

Drupal's CCK module gives me exactly what I need, and I'm trying to understand if I can get this capability with DNN (or do I have to code it myself). Most of the developers in my company work in .NET languages to there's a significant advantage for me to work with DNN.

Comment: It's not clear to me if you are building a Content Management System yourself or simply creating a site using a content management system as a backend (with possibly some custom plugin/module). Would you mind to clarify this?

Comment: @mac: I want to use a CMS such as Drupal or DNN, not to create one myself. Thanks for clarifying its not clear.

Comment: @Rax - I edited and added more info in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look into one of the following DNN modules:

- [DNN Content Builder](http://www.codeplex.com/dnncb)
- [DNNMasters Content Builder Pro 2.x with Ajax](http://www.snowcovered.com/snowcovered2/Default.aspx?PackageID=8534&tabid=242)

The second of these looks like the more powerful but, unlike the first, is not free.

Comment: +1 thanks, these seem to be in the right direction. I will have to learn them to see if they indeed provide the functionality I need.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer, in, 2011, is no, even with special modules, there's nothing that rivals Drupal's CCK / Fields API in DNN.

The Tab->Module approach is fundamentally flawed in this respect.